# Set drop down list's selected value according to the database retrieved

Tags: java, html, mysql, jsp, servlets

I am trying to do an update form in my jsp. I need help in setting the drop down list display to the value retrieved from database. So when the user wants to edit a particular row of data, they will just need to click on the update button corresponding to it and the data will be shown in the form.

I am able to use `input type="text" name="expenseTitle" style="margin-left:12px" value="<%=rec.getString("expense_title")%>">`to retrieve data to my textbox.

I am using this connection to connect and retrieve my database:

```
<%
    Connection connect = null;
    Statement s = null;

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        connect =  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/asldb" + "?user=root&password=mysql");

        s = connect.createStatement();
         String id = request.getParameter("id");  

        String sql = "SELECT * FROM input_expense WHERE id = '" + id +"'"; 

        ResultSet rec = s.executeQuery(sql);
        if(rec != null) {
            rec.next();

%>
```

I have tried several methods. Firstly, for this method, no matter which row I use, it always retrieve Yearly in drop down list:

```
<select id="LT_occurrenceDDL" class="LT_formDDL" name="expenseOccurrence">
                    <option value="-1">Select an option</option>
                    <option value="One-Time" selected="<%=rec.getString("payment_occurrence").equals("One-Time")%>">One-Time</option>
                    <option value="Daily" selected="<%=rec.getString("payment_occurrence").equals("Daily")%>">Daily</option>
                    <option value="Weekly" selected="<%=rec.getString("payment_occurrence").equals("Weekly")%>">Weekly</option>
                    <option value="Monthly" selected="<%=rec.getString("payment_occurrence").equals("Monthly")%>">Monthly</option>
                    <option value="Quarterly" selected="<%=rec.getString("payment_occurrence").equals("Quarterly")%>">Quarterly</option>
                    <option value="Yearly" selected="<%=rec.getString("payment_occurrence").equals("Yearly")%>">Yearly</option>
                </select>
```

Secondly:

```
<select class="LT_formDDL" name="expenseCategory"">
                    <option value="-1">Select a category</option>
                    <option value="mortgage/rent" <%= (rec.getString("expense_category")=="Mortgage/Rent Payment"?"selected='selected'":"")%>>Mortgage/Rent Payment</option>
                    <option value="loan" <%= (rec.getString("expense_category")=="Loans"?"selected='selected'":"")%>>Loans</option>
                    <option value="insurance" <%= (rec.getString("expense_category")=="Insurance"?"selected='selected'":"")%>>Insurance</option>
                    <option value="utilities" <%= (rec.getString("expense_category")=="Utilities"?"selected='selected'":"")%>>Utilities</option>
                    <option value="groceries" <%= (rec.getString("expense_category")=="Groceries"?"selected='selected'":"")%>>Groceries</option>
                    <option value="food" <%= (rec.getString("expense_category")=="Food"?"selected='selected'":"")%>>Food</option>
                    <option value="clothing" <%= (rec.getString("expense_category")=="Clothing"?"selected='selected'":"")%>>Clothing</option>
                    <option value="entertainment" <%= (rec.getString("expense_category")=="Entertainment"?"selected='selected'":"")%>>Entertainment</option>
                    <option value="others" <%= (rec.getString("expense_category")=="Others"?"selected='selected'":"")%>>Others</option>
                </select>
```

Thirdly, I have input jar and the taglib:

```
<select id="LT_occurrenceDDL"class="LT_formDDL" name="expenseOccurrence">
                    <option value="-1">Select an option</option>
                    <c:choose>
                    <c:when test='${rec.getString("payment_occurrence") == "One-Time"}'>
                    <option value="One-Time" selected>One-Time</option>
                    </c:when>
                    <c:otherwise>
                    <option value="One-Time">One-Time</option>
                    </c:otherwise>
                    </c:choose>
                    <c:choose>
                    <c:when test='${rec.getString("payment_occurrence") == "Daily"}'>
                    <option value="Daily" selected>Daily</option>
                    </c:when>
                    <c:otherwise>
                    <option value="Daily">Daily</option>
                    </c:otherwise>
                    </c:choose>
                    <c:choose>
                    <c:when test='${rec.getString("payment_occurrence") == "Weekly"}'>
                    <option value="Weekly" selected>Weekly</option>
                    </c:when>
                    <c:otherwise>
                    <option value="Weekly">Weekly</option>
                    </c:otherwise>
                    </c:choose>
                    <c:choose>
                    <c:when test='${rec.getString("payment_occurrence") == "Monthly"}'>
                    <option value="Monthly" selected>Monthly</option>
                    </c:when>
                    <c:otherwise>
                    <option value="Monthly">Monthly</option>
                    </c:otherwise>
                    </c:choose>
                    <c:choose>
                    <c:when test='${rec.getString("payment_occurrence") == "Quarterly"}'>
                    <option value="Quarterly" selected>Quarterly</option>
                    </c:when>
                    <c:otherwise>
                    <option value="Quarterly">Quarterly</option>
                    </c:otherwise>
                    </c:choose>
                    <c:choose>
                    <c:when test='${rec.getString("payment_occurrence") == "Yearly"}'>
                    <option value="Yearly" selected>Yearly</option>
                    </c:when>
                    <c:otherwise>
                    <option value="Yearly">Yearly</option>
                    </c:otherwise>
                    </c:choose>
                </select>
```

Sorry the drop down list is different for some because I have a few drop down list in the form, thus I tried different once using different method.

Answer (score 0):

As for me, you should create two .jsp pages to do what you want. First one will display all users you have with the `update` and `create` buttoms and second one will display user that you want to update (with current `id`). You can forward your request without updating of main page only using Ajax. For more information please look at this test project [test](https://danielniko.wordpress.com/2012/04/17/simple-crud-using-jsp-servlet-and-mysql/)

Answer (score 0):

It seems You are only using the first row of resultset without iteration. You should iterate the resultset like this -

```
if(rec!=null){
  while(rec.next()){
     // your retrieval code 
  }
}
```

I think this might solve the problem